# How to set the scroll bar to div container inside of the section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I forgot to mention that this page is inside of the iframe. Here is the code for my iframe:

```
<iframe src="pgHome.html" name="hmFrame" id="hmFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

If I set scrolling = "yes" my entire frame will scroll but I still can't get the scrolling to work on my div container.

I have a some problems to set the scroll bar on the div container. This container loads the table for each item from navigation bar. Some tables can't fit on the screen. I would like to set the scroll bar on the div container or on the tables. Here is my HTML table:

```js
$('.xNavigation a').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    $('#dataContainer > div[id=' + id + ']').show();
    $('#dataContainer > div:not([id=' + id + '])').hide();
 });
```

```css
div.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
}
aside.sidebar {
    width: 120px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 0;
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
}
aside.sidebar h3 {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #000099;
 color: white;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 2px;
}
section.mainBox{
 min-width: 1000px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 padding-top: 0;
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height: 800px;
}
section.mainBox h3 {
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #000099;
 color: white;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 2px;
}

div #dataContainer > div:not([id="tbl1"]) {
   display: none;
}
nav.yNavigation {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #c8e2db;
}
nav.yNavigation ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
nav.yNavigation a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
}
nav.yNavigation a:hover {
 color: #999999;
}
nav.xNavigation {
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 padding-top: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 background-color: #c8e2db;
 float: left;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 min-height: 18px;
}
nav.xNavigation a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}
nav.xNavigation a:hover {
 color: #999999;
}
div.frRow {
 margin: 5px;
 display: table;
}
div.frCell {
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 5px;
}
table.tblData {
 border: #ccc 1px solid;
 margin: 10px;
 border-radius:3px;
}
table.tblData caption {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 background-color: #ededed;
 border: #ccc 1px solid;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
table.tblData th {
 padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
 border-top:1px solid #fafafa;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
 background: #ededed;
 text-align: center;
}
table.tblData td {
 padding:5px;
 border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
 border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 background-color: #c8e2db;
 min-width: 30px;
 text-align: left; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=11" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
 <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <aside class="sidebar">
   <h3>Menu</h3>
   <nav class="yNavigation">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="pgHome.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="pgReports.html">Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </aside>
  <section class="mainBox">
   <h3>Home Page</h3>
   <nav class="xNavigation">
    <a href="#" id="tbl1">Table 1</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tbl2">Table 2</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tbl3">Table 3</a> |
   </nav>
   <form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" action="pgHome.html" method="POST">
    <div class="frRow">
     <div class="frCell">
      <select name="myMenu" id="myMenu" style="width:80px;">
       <option value="1">Name</option>
       <option value="2">DOB</option>
       <option value="3">ID</option>
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="frCell">
      <input type="text" name="searchFld" id="searchFld" size="24" maxlength="24" value="" title="Maximum size of the field is 24 characters." />
     </div>
     <div class="frCell">
      <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
   <div id="dataContainer">

    <!--- Table 1 --->
    <div id="tbl1">
     <table class="tblData">
      <caption>User Info 1</caption>
      <tr>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <td colspan="2" id="st_lname"></td>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <td colspan="2" id="st_fname"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>DOB</th>
       <td colspan="2" id="st_dob"></td>
       <th>Age</th>
       <td colspan="2" id="st_age"></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>

    <!--- Table 2 --->
    <div id="tbl2">
     <table class="tblData">
      <caption>User Info 2</caption>
      <tr>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1LName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1FName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
       <th>Email</th>
       <td id="fi_email"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number H</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1PhoneH"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number W</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1PhoneW"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number C</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1PhoneC"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th rowspan="2">Adrress</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1AddrLine1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="fi_adult1AddrLine2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>City</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1City"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>State</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1State"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Zip</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1Zip"></td>
      </tr>
     </table> 
     <table class="tblData">
      <caption>User Info 3</caption>
      <tr>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2LName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2FName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Email</th>
       <td id="fi_email2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number H</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2PhoneH"></td>
      </tr>
       <th>Phone Number W</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2PhoneW"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number C</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2PhoneC"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th rowspan="2">Adrress</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2AddrLine1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
       <td id="fi_adult2AddrLine2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>City</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2City"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>State</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2State"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Zip</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2Zip"></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>

    <!--- Table 3 --->
    <div id="tbl3">
     <table class="tblData">
      <tr><th>Some Data</th></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So my first question is where is the best place to put the scroll bar? Also I want to make my side bar and top bar static. If user scroll the page those two should remain visible on the top. Also on the tablets and mobile devices with the small screen size this will require some scrolling. Is there better way to handle this problem with CSS/HTML 5/JQuery?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid with the script not being contained within the `<head>`. You are also claiming XHTML but you are not serving XHTML. Also, the meta tag does not have a closing slash.

Comment: I thought that script tag can be outside of html tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `overflow: scroll` on `#dataContainer`

Comment: I did set overflow:scroll on my div container and still my page can't scroll. I can see the bars fro scrolling by the way.

Comment: Based on your example, it's not scrolling because the tables aren't long enough. If you set `height: 500px` on `mainBox` then the 2nd table scrolls because it's longer than the height of `mainBox`.

Comment: I have tried to remove overflow-y:scroll in mainBox set the height to 500px and add the overflow scroll to data Container but that still did not let me scroll.

Comment: The problem is that you've got the scroll on one and the height on the other. If you want only the table to scroll and not any of the menus, then move `overflow: scroll` to `#dataContainer` and set a fixed height on it. If you want all of `mainBox` to scroll, including the menus, then set `overflow: scroll` on `mainBox` and reduce its height.

Comment: Well I tried that. Set dataContainer height to 400px and overflow:scroll but that works in Chrome only. In Mozilla my page is still frozen I can't scroll.

Comment: It works in FF for me. Btw, it will only scroll for **Table 2** in your example, because the other two tables are too short.

Comment: I got it to work finally. Thanks for your help. Do you have any advice on how to make this fit smaller screen size?

Comment: You could use something like bootstrap which is built to be responsive to smaller screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You must set the height on **#dataContainer**  not on **.mainBox**

```
div #dataContainer{
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

and

```
 section.mainBox{
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-y: scroll;  //remove this
    height: 800px;  //remove this
 }
```

```js
$('.xNavigation a').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    $('#dataContainer > div[id=' + id + ']').show();
    $('#dataContainer > div:not([id=' + id + '])').hide();
 });
```

```css
div.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
}
aside.sidebar {
    width: 120px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 0;
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
}
aside.sidebar h3 {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #000099;
 color: white;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 2px;
}
section.mainBox{    //Modified
 min-width: 100%;
 margin-left: 5px;
 padding-top: 0;
 float: left;
 background-color: white;

}
#dataContainer{   //Added
 height:200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}
section.mainBox h3 {
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #000099;
 color: white;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 2px;
}

div #dataContainer > div:not([id="tbl1"]) {
   display: none;
}
nav.yNavigation {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #c8e2db;
}
nav.yNavigation ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
nav.yNavigation a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
}
nav.yNavigation a:hover {
 color: #999999;
}
nav.xNavigation {
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 padding-top: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 background-color: #c8e2db;
 float: left;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 min-height: 18px;
}
nav.xNavigation a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}
nav.xNavigation a:hover {
 color: #999999;
}
div.frRow {
 margin: 5px;
 display: table;
}
div.frCell {
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 5px;
}
table.tblData {
 border: #ccc 1px solid;
 margin: 10px;
 border-radius:3px;
}
table.tblData caption {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 background-color: #ededed;
 border: #ccc 1px solid;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
table.tblData th {
 padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
 border-top:1px solid #fafafa;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
 background: #ededed;
 text-align: center;
}
table.tblData td {
 padding:5px;
 border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
 border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 background-color: #c8e2db;
 min-width: 30px;
 text-align: left; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=11" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
 <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <aside class="sidebar">
   <h3>Menu</h3>
   <nav class="yNavigation">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="pgHome.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="pgReports.html">Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </aside>
  <section class="mainBox">
   <h3>Home Page</h3>
   <nav class="xNavigation">
    <a href="#" id="tbl1">Table 1</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tbl2">Table 2</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tbl3">Table 3</a> |
   </nav>
   <form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" action="pgHome.html" method="POST">
    <div class="frRow">
     <div class="frCell">
      <select name="myMenu" id="myMenu" style="width:80px;">
       <option value="1">Name</option>
       <option value="2">DOB</option>
       <option value="3">ID</option>
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="frCell">
      <input type="text" name="searchFld" id="searchFld" size="24" maxlength="24" value="" title="Maximum size of the field is 24 characters." />
     </div>
     <div class="frCell">
      <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
   <div id="dataContainer">

    <!--- Table 1 --->
    <div id="tbl1">
     <table class="tblData">
      <caption>User Info 1</caption>
      <tr>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <td colspan="2" id="st_lname"></td>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <td colspan="2" id="st_fname"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>DOB</th>
       <td colspan="2" id="st_dob"></td>
       <th>Age</th>
       <td colspan="2" id="st_age"></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>

    <!--- Table 2 --->
    <div id="tbl2">
     <table class="tblData">
      <caption>User Info 2</caption>
      <tr>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1LName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1FName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
       <th>Email</th>
       <td id="fi_email"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number H</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1PhoneH"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number W</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1PhoneW"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number C</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1PhoneC"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th rowspan="2">Adrress</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1AddrLine1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="fi_adult1AddrLine2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>City</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1City"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>State</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1State"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Zip</th>
       <td id="fi_adult1Zip"></td>
      </tr>
     </table> 
     <table class="tblData">
      <caption>User Info 3</caption>
      <tr>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2LName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2FName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Email</th>
       <td id="fi_email2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number H</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2PhoneH"></td>
      </tr>
       <th>Phone Number W</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2PhoneW"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Phone Number C</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2PhoneC"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th rowspan="2">Adrress</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2AddrLine1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
       <td id="fi_adult2AddrLine2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>City</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2City"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>State</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2State"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Zip</th>
       <td id="fi_adult2Zip"></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>

    <!--- Table 3 --->
    <div id="tbl3">
     <table class="tblData">
      <tr><th>Some Data</th></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property [css overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow?v=example) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the div overflow to scroll.